# Dense Compact subset of $X = ((\beta(D) \times (\mathfrak{c}^+ + 1)) \setminus (\beta(D) \setminus D) \times \{\mathfrak{c}^+\})$

Tags: general-topology, compactness, ordinals, product-space

Let $D$ be a discrete space of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ and $\beta(D)$ is the Stone Cech compactification of $D$. Let
$$
X = ((\beta(D) \times (\mathfrak{c}^+ + 1)) \setminus (\beta(D) \setminus D) \times \{\mathfrak{c}^+\})
$$
be the subspace of the product space $\beta(D) \times (\mathfrak{c}^+ + 1)$. Does $X$ has a dense compact subset in $X$, if yes, then what that subset would be.

If not, then here is my another question:

If $\mathcal{U}$ be any family of pairwise disjoint nonempty open sets in $X$, then can we find a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that $K$ intersects with every member of $\mathcal{U}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\beta$ here?

Comment: Which topology does $\mathfrak{c}^+ + 1$ have? The order topology?

Comment: If  $\mathfrak{c}^+ + 1$ has the order topology, then $X$ is T2. Hence a compact subspace of $X$ is closed and therefore not dense, since X is not compact.

Comment: Yes $\mathfrak{c}^+ + 1$ has the order topology.

Comment: I am modifying my question. If $\mathcal{U}$ be any family of pairwise disjoint non empty open sets, can we find a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that $K$ intersects with every member of $\mathcal{U}$.